# Add a cookie warning message to site

Tags: cookies

We plan to implement "the privacy warning displays on every page load until the visitor gives consent". Currently, we're using `Sitecore 10.1`. Our solution is in `MVC`.

Could you please share how you implemented this in your project? If it is a third-party, which is better in terms of simple integration and pricing.

I found a link to enable the `Cookie Consent` form in `SXA`. But did not find any article for custom solutions in `Sitecore MVC`.

[https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/add-a-cookie-warning-message-to-your-site.html#:~:text=To%20add%20a%20cookie%20warning,%3E%2FSettings%2FPrivacy%20Warning.&text=Enter%20your%20cookie%20warning%20statement.&text=Enter%20the%20button%20text](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/add-a-cookie-warning-message-to-your-site.html#:%7E:text=To%20add%20a%20cookie%20warning,%3E%2FSettings%2FPrivacy%20Warning.&text=Enter%20your%20cookie%20warning%20statement.&text=Enter%20the%20button%20text).

I got the following third party solution while searching.

1. Cookiebot : https://www.cookiebot.com/en/

Cookiebot is used in `Sitecore TDS` website (https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/).

2. Secureprivacy -  https://secureprivacy.ai/technology/sitecore
3. Cookie Information Consent Management Platform - https://cookieinformation.com/extension/sitecore/

Comment: Do you have a specific question around cookie consent implementation?  This is a pretty open-ended topic and I think you'll have better luck getting help if you can share more context around the challenge that you're trying to overcome.

Comment: Hi Chet Cheeto, I am mainly looking for solution, what is best way to implement in Sitecore MVC. Custom solution or any third-party tool.